# one object follows two different paths

Tags: path

(Blender 3)
I have an object that I want to go in a straight line then immediately after follow a circle path.  This has taken 5 hours of my day but no progress. Here's what I've tried.

1. add > path.  select object > add constraint of follow path.  Modify the path so it looks a bit like a straight line then curves in a lasso.  It has been very hard to get the nice circular motion I want.
2. animation/key frames to move the object in a straight path.  Then create a circle at the end of the path and use 'follow path'.   However I can't get the timing right so that when one ends the other begins.  I tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHPk8BsJuuM&ab_channel=BlenderStudy), but in graph view with the circle selected I don't see the options he describes.
3. create two follow paths.  one a straight line and the other a circle.  I was hopeful!!   The goal was to reduce influence from 1->0 at the end of the line, and bring up influence for the circle to "pass it over".   Fail.  I am unable to automate the influence function.  I move the frame, I try to reduce influence before setting keyframe.. but every time I reduce influence it moves my object back to the start of the path.  I guess I am messing this step up.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind explaining under 2. which options you don't see? The sidebar panel? He hits 'N' to bring it up as he says in the video. Or which options do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to get your first version correct or the circle more round than your lasso version:

1. Add a *Bézier Circle* and in *Edit View* select the bottom control point when viewing from top down onto the circle.

[image: select point]

2. Then hit <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> to extrude the point on the X axis.

[image: extrude point]

3. This seems to mess up the circle a lot because it is still cyclic and the new point is connected in both directions. To fix this, go to the *Curve* menu and choose *Toggle Cyclic*. You could also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as long as you have any point selected.

[image: toggle cyclic]

4. Since the bottom point of the circle was the end point of the curve and it is no longer cyclic, the new point is no longer connected in both directions.

[image: unconnected point]

5. Now in order to fix the circle back to its original shape, select one of the two points at the bottom of the circle (you can see only one because they are in the same place). Let's say you grab the end point - the one with handles going from top left to bottom right as in the following screenshot:

[image: end point]

6. With this point select, press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate it, type '-45' and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the rotation.

[image: rotate -45]

7. Now select the other point in this location, the one with the handles from top right to bottom left, with the latter being longer than the other.

[image: start point]

8. Rotate it half as much as the first point in the opposite direction, i.e. press <kbd>R</kbd>, type '22.5' and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: rotate 22.5]

Now the circle is back in its original shape. The control point you have extruded in X direction can be moved further out if you need a longer path to follow.

Answer (score 0):

All three of your options are reasonable and doable; any problems you're having with them can be addressed.  However, the first technique you've tried is probably the simplest, and the only hard part here is, how to connect a straight section to a circle without screwing up the circle.  Let's see how we can do that:

1. Start by creating a bezier circle and entering edit on it.  Anything we do to this curve, we'll be doing in edit mode; that will leave our curve untransformed, appropriate for intuitive behavior on a follow path constraint from another object that is untransformed.
2. Select all curve controls + handles and set the handle type of these handles to "free".  This will allow us to add and disconnect segments without changing the curvature of unaltered segments.
3. Toggle cyclic on the curve.  A path has a beginning and end.  When you toggle cyclic, you will see that we lose a segment (no worries, it's easy to get back), but because we have set our handles to free type, the curvature doesn't change:

[image]

I've given my curve a bit of bevel depth so we can see what we're doing better.

4. To make a straight section, we can switch to "normal" orientation, then select a control on one end or the other, and extrude it.  To extrude it, type 'e' then 'z' then move your mouse to constrain the extrusion to the normal Z axis-- which in the case of a curve control, means the direction of the curve's tangent:

[image]

We only have 3/4ths of a circle.  Let's say that we want to do 540 degrees to come back out the way we came in a straight line.  That should demonstrate what we need to do for most situations.

To create additional sections, we'll start by selecting and duplicating controls.  Don't worry if they're joined or not.  I'll just duplicate my entire circle and then move it up one Z unit (via snap to increment), so that we can see what we're doing:

[image]

Now let's join two segments, by selecting two controls and 'f' to connect them, and delete a control on the end:

[image]

We can extrude the end of the path in the same way we did the beginning, then move our section back down a single unit in Z, since we no longer need to see what we're doing:

[image]

Of course, we can edit this curvature however we'd like.  It's safe to use "aligned" handle types, but the default "automatic" will probably change the curvature in ways you dislike.  So long as we do basic operations on our entire curve, all of its controls and handles together, we'll maintain this same curvature.  We can scale it up; we can scale it up in a single axis to make an ellipsoid; we can rotate the entire thing about its center, perhaps if we wanted our intro and exit lines to be at an angle to our world axes.